# How can I populate a dropdown list based on selection of another drop down list without using ajax, PHP?

Tags: php, html, pdo, dropdown

I have a mySQL table that has a list of modules and possible times. This is how the table looks:

```
+-----------------------+------------------+----------+
| Module                | Date             | Status   |
+-----------------------+------------------+----------+
| Chemistry             | Tuesday, 10:00   |      full|
| Chemistry             | Wednesday, 11:00 |      full|
| Chemistry             | Thursday, 12:00  |     empty|
| Chemistry             | Thursday, 11:00  |      full|
| Biology               | Tuesday, 10:00   |      full|
| Biology               | Wednesday, 12:00 |      full|
| Biology               | Tuesday, 12:00   |      full|
| Business              | Wednesday, 10:00 |     empty|
| Law                   | Thursday, 11:00  |     empty|
| Law                   | Thursday, 10:00  |      full|
+-----------------------+------------------+----------+
```

I have two drop down menus that are populated from this database, for the user to select the Module and Date, So that they can view the status:

```
//start form for drop down list for Modules
echo<<<FORMSTART
   <form name= "topic_list" method= "post">
   <select name = "Module selected: ">
   <option value = "None">Select a Module</option>
FORMSTART;

   $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT Module from sessions");

   //populate drop down menu
     while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo "<option value= '" . $row['Module'] . "'>". $row    ['Module'] . "</option>";
     }
   //End form for drop down menu
echo<<<FORMEND
</select>
</form>
FORMEND;
   //start form for drop down list for Date
echo<<<FORMSTART
   <form name= "Date_list" method= "post">
   <select name = "Date selected: ">
   <option value = "None">Select a Date</option>
FORMSTART;

   $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT Date from sessions");

   //populate drop down menu
     while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo "<option value= '" . $row['Date'] . "'>". $row    ['Times'] . "</option>";
     }
   //End form for drop down menu
echo<<<FORMEND
</select>
</form>
FORMEND;
```

How can I make sure the second drop down menu for the dates is not populated with all the dates in the table but only the dates for the specific Module?

Also, How to I ensure the Dates and modules of those modules with status "full" is not included in the drop down menus?

If there is a way I can improve my question please let me know. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you find out the selected module and use `query("SELECT Date FROM sessions WHERE Module='" . $selected_module . "'");` in your second query?

Comment: @newplayer65 The second query is happening when creating the page, not after the user submits the form.

Comment: You need to do this in Javascript. Have the PHP create a Javascript object that lists the times of each module. Then when the user changes the module dropdown, it populates the date dropdown with the corresponding times.

Comment: Then only query for and populate the second list after an item in the first is selected, and make it query again if they change the first item. EDIT: as @Barmar said, javascript is probably the way to go.

Comment: @newplayer65 WIthout Javascript, that would require submitting the form twice, first for the module, then for the date.

Comment: @Barmar which is why I agree javascript is more suitable for the job than PHP, but still doable with PHP.

Comment: but I want to know how to do it with php :)

Comment: This is what I have now but the dates are not being populated in the drop down menu:

Comment: Essentially you need 2 separate PHP pages for each dropdown. The first is where you select your module, second page gets which module you selected with the form output and uses the query I mentioned above to populate the menu. Then you can make custom back/skip/submit buttons for the different pages.

Comment: On top of that, you can make smooth, elegant, multi-dimensional forms in that manner.

Comment: any tutorial page you can suggest so I learn to do that? @newplayer65

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp is a good place to get started. I also suggest looking at https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/retrieve-html-form-data-with-php/ to get familiar with URL Query Strings. What you want to do is send the Module name from the first form to the next PHP page where you assign that name to a variable `$selected_module` and use the SQL query I commented above to push the correct items into the list.

Comment: You can do submit form - via - `onchange="this.form.submit();"` attribute in your select tag. And then based on the submitted select value, populate the next drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated the most simple and user-friendly solution would involve AJAX. Another client-side only option would be to pre-load all required data into JavaScript and write a bit of client-side logic to filter the dates by the selected module.

However, if you want to go with the old-school approach with minimal JavaScript it is relatively straight-forward:

- Add a hook to your module select field to submit the form when it changes - preferably a `GET` rather than `POST` to avoid the browser from asking the user if they want to re-submit their data if they refresh the page.
- Submit the form to the same PHP file that loads the form.
- Inside the PHP script check if the module was sent via `$_GET` or `$_POST`.
- If it is then run your date query with the specified module in a `WHERE` clause, otherwise show all dates (or show no dates - depending on your use case).
- You will also have to populate any other values in your form that were also submitted in `$_GET`.

As for your second question: I think you just want to add a `WHERE` clause to your query, e.g.

```
SELECT `Date` from `sessions` WHERE `Status` != "full";
```

Side note: Not sure if `Date` or `Status` are reserved in MySQL. Either way it's good practice to wrap tables and columns in backticks.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this approach